# How, if shape1.brush.color:=clred and shape2.brush.color:=clred then DO SOMETHING?

Tags: delphi, if-statement, colors, shapes, brush

When I run application with these two codes, shows same error:

> Operator not applicable to this operand type

```
procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If (shape1.Brush.Color:=clblue and shape2.Brush.Color:=clblue) then
  begin
    showMessage('error');
  end;

procedure TForm1.Button4Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  If (shape1.Brush.Color:=clblue) and (shape2.Brush.Color:=clblue) then
  begin
    showMessage('error');
  end;
```

Comment: @SirRufo, the error message is actually a compiler error.

Comment: @UweRaabe Upps, I was just looking at the other failure :o)

Answer (score 6):

There are two problems here.

First, the operator being used, `:=`, is an assignment, not an equality check.  For that, you want `=`.

Second, multiple comparisons in the same expression require parenthesis around each individual comparison, due to precedence problems with the `and` and `or` operators.  So what you want is:

```
if (shape1.Brush.Color = clblue) and (shape2.Brush.Color = clblue) then
begin
  showMessage('error');
end;
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, `:=` is not an operator at all.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: How do you figure?  I've always heard it called "the assignment operator."

Comment: Because in Pascal `:=` does not return a value and cannot participate in expression. Borland help carefully states "sometimes called the assignment operator".

Comment: @FreeConsulting: True, but how is that relevant to the definition of an operator?

Comment: If `:=` would be (or behave like) an operator then OP's expression would became `if TColorTypedValue and TColorTypedValue then ...`.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: Why?  Where in the definition of *operator* (a built-in symbol or keyword that performs an operation) does it say that the operation in question must return a value?

Comment: @FreeConsulting: According to the [Delphi language guide](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Assignment_Statements): "The := symbol is sometimes called the assignment operator." Mason is correct in the use of the phrase, according to that page. (And in my opinion your quibbling over semantics isn't helpful to a new user, which clearly applies to the poster of this question Why confuse Mason's answer by debating some nitpick detail in the comments?)

Comment: @Free It's rather petty and pointless to invent your own private terminology and then chide others for not abiding by that terminology.

Comment: @KenWhite, according to the phrase in my citation you've managed to overlook and carefully cite again, Mason is ***sometimes** correct in that use*. And **sometimes** (like in this case) using slang (a.k.a. a terminology private to Pascal/Delphi users) is misleading. That is, even new users should not be introduced in confusion of `:=` with the [other] operators. Dixi.

Comment: @FreeConsulting: It's hardly private to Pascal.  In the C family, `=` is called the assignment operator too.  Are you from a FP background or something?  Because you seem to have this weird idea stuck in your head that a "real operator" must necessarily return a value, and that's simply not true in imperative programming.

Comment: Be careful, @Mason. In C and C++, the `=` operator actually does conform to Free's definition of operator (except in C++ when it's been overloaded to return `void`).

Comment: @RobKennedy Of course there are certainly C and C++ operators that do not yield values so the point Mason makes is quite valid

Answer (score 3):

You should reread your Delphi manual!

A comparison for equality is a simple `=`, while a `:=` is used for an assignment.